# Import scraped data via secure proxy into Google Sheets

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need to import data into Google Sheets from a secure website that can only be accessed if I'm connected to a specific server via VPN.  Is there a way to do this?

I've tried using the `importhtml` and `importxml` functions and they didn't work.

```
=importhtml("https://website","table",1) <-- Did not work
```

The error I'm getting is

> `#N/A` - Could not fetch URL

Answer (score 0):

no, that is not possible. in order to import data into Google Sheets, the source website needs to be public and not behind a login. also, any kind of JavaScript is not supported.